# Getting a Microsoft Teams Graph API "Application with AAD App Id 'xxxx' is not authorized to generate custom text notifications..."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We are getting the following error whilst trying to send activity notifications to users in a chat for our custom application:

> Application with AAD App Id '{APPID}' is not authorized to generate custom text notifications about '/beta/users/{USERID}/teamwork/Microsoft.Teams.GraphSvc.sendActivityNotification' to the recipient. Ensure that the expected Teams app is installed in the target scope (user, team, or chat).

We have spent a long time perusing the documentation and examining the various options & parameters which we could adjust, but are hitting the same error.
Any assistance would be appreciated at this point.

---

The url is: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/19:{CHANNELID}/sendActivityNotification"

Payload looks like this:

```
{
  topic: {
    source: 'text',
    value: '@mention',
    webUrl: 'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/{ENTITYID}/_djb2_msteams_prefix_1474050903?context={"subEntityId":null,"channelId":"19:{CHANNELID}"&groupId={GROUPID}&tenantId={TENANTID}'
  },
  activityType: 'userMention',
  previewText: { content: '@mention' },
  recipient: {
    '@odata.type': 'microsoft.graph.aadUserNotificationRecipient',
    userId: '{USERID}'
  },
  templateParameters: [
    { name: 'firstName', value: 'John' },
    { name: 'lastName', value: 'Smith' }
  ]
}
```

As the title says, the error returned is an authorization error:

> Application with AAD App Id '{APPID}' is not authorized to generate custom text notifications about '/beta/users/{USERID}/teamwork/Microsoft.Teams.GraphSvc.sendActivityNotification' to the recipient. Ensure that the expected Teams app is installed in the target scope (user, team, or chat).

The manifest includes the following:

```
    "webApplicationInfo":{
      "id":"{APPID}",
      "resource": "https://notapplicable",
      "applicationPermissions": [
        "TeamsActivity.Send.Group",
        "Microsoft.Teams.GraphSvc.sendActivityNotification"
      ]
    },
    "permissions": [
       "identity", "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "configurableTabs": [
      {
        ...
        "scopes": [ "team", "groupchat"],
        "context": ["channelTab", "privateChatTab"]
      }
    ]
```

Our app has the following permissions in the Teams Admin Center:

- Create new notifications in the teamwork activity feeds of the users in this team.
- Microsoft.Teams.GraphSvc.sendActivityNotification

Our Azure AD app API permissions has the following:

| API / Permissions name | Type | Description | Admin consent required | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ChannelMember.Read.All | Application | Read the members of all channels | Yes | Granted for Default Directory |
| ChannelMessage.Send | Delegated | Send channel messages | No |  |
| ChannelSettings.Read.All | Application | Read the names, descriptions, and settings of all channels | Yes | Granted for Default Directory |
| ChatMember.Read.All | Application | Read the members of all chats | Yes | Granted for Default Directory |
| Organization.Read.All | Application | Read organization information | Yes | Granted for Default Directory |
| OrgContact.Read.All | Application | Read organizational contacts | Yes | Granted for Default Directory |
| Team.ReadBasic.All | Application | Get a list of all teams | Yes | Granted for Default Directory |
| TeamMember.Read.All | Application | Read the members of all teams | Yes | Granted for Default Directory |
| TeamsActivity.Send | Delegated | Send a teamwork activity as the user | No |  |
| TeamsActivity.Send | Application | Send a teamwork activity to any user | Yes | Granted for Default Directory |
| User.Read | Delegated | Sign in and read user profile | No | Granted for Default Directory |
| User.Read.All | Application | Read all users' full profiles | Yes | Granted for Default Directory |

.

Comment: Hello Martin - Looks like you are passing channel id rather than team id, while calling the API.
Can you please check once.

Comment: Hi @ChetanSharma-msft I get the same response if the url has the `teamId` instead of `channelId`

Comment: @MartinBarnard - Could you please confirm once the Azure app id you are using for your app is same as the app id you are getting in the error response. If yes, check once if the app is installed in target scope (in teams or group chat) form where you are trying to send the notification.

Comment: @MartinBarnard - Could you please confirm if the above suggestion helped you in any way or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I have fixed the issue. The suggestions did not help.

For anybody wondering, the `groupId` in the Microsoft Teams context corresponds to the `teamId` in Graph API. If you are sending notifications, you will need to use the endpoint `/team/{groupId}/sendActivityNotification`

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer from comment section for more visibility.

**groupId** in the Microsoft Teams context corresponds to the **teamId** in Graph API.

If you are sending notifications, you will need to use the endpoint **/team/{groupId}/sendActivityNotification**